# Angular with Rails - Angular template will not load properly

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, angularjs-routing

i am learning how to use angularjs routing and templating, and i have come across a problem. I have added the gem in Gemfile, added //= require angular-rails-templates in application.js, and added the dependancy in my main angular.module. Everything seems ok but the templates are not rendering properly.

```
angular.module('authentication', ['authenticationModule','ngRoute','templates'])
    .config(['$routeProvider',function($provider){
        $provider
            .when('/sign_in', { templateUrl: 'assets/signin.html', controller: 'redirectCtrl'})

            .when('/sign_up', { templateUrl: 'assets/signup.html', controller: 'redirectCtrl1'})
    }])
    .controller('redirectCtrl', function($location) {
        // $location.path('/sign_in')
    })
    .controller('redirectCtrl1', function($location) {
        // $location.path('/sign_up')
    })
```

And here is what i get, the template loads but with some extra stuff that i dont need http://postimg.org/image/iuhy9dflj/

Here is the code in my register page, that should render

```
<div ng-controller="authenticationCtrl">    
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <div>
        <div>
          <div>Email: <input ng-model="email1" type="email"/></div>
          <div>Password: <input type="password" ng-model="password1" /></div>
          <div>Password Confirmation: <input type="password" ng-model="password2" /></div>

          <button ng-click="register()" >Register</button>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

And my application.js included files

```
//= require angular
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require angular-animate
//= require angular-resource
//= require devise-min
//= require angular-route.min
//= require angular-rails-templates
//= require_tree ../templates
```

Comment: Have exactly same problem. Will update if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "assets" from your templateUrl. So it should be:

```
templateUrl: 'signin.html'
```

instead of

```
templateUrl: 'assets/signin.html'
```

angular-rails-templates caches the templates without the "assets" in the path.